# Create View in Athena but "column name specified more than once"

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have created a SELECT query that joins three tables in AWS Athena - the query itself works...

```
Select t1.*, t2.*, t3.*
from "analytics_poc"."stg_orderitem" as t1
INNER Join "analytics_poc"."stg_orderitemtag" as t2
ON t1.orderitemid=t2.orderitemid
LEFT Join "analytics_poc"."stg_tag" as t3
ON t3.tagid=t2.tagid
```

However, when I try to create a VIEW from this query I get this error...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW "CMS_orderitem_tags"
AS 
Select t1.*, t2.*, t3.*
from "analytics_poc"."stg_orderitem" as t1
INNER Join "analytics_poc"."stg_orderitemtag" as t2
ON t1.orderitemid=t2.orderitemid
LEFT Join "analytics_poc"."stg_tag" as t3
ON t3.tagid=t2.tagid
```

```
line 1:1: Column name 'orderitemid' specified more than once.
```

Does anyone know why this is the case?

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that a column called `orderitemid` exists in more than one of those tables.

The `SELECT` command doesn't mind having multiple output columns with the same name, but `CREATE VIEW` doesn't allow it.

You could try `USING` instead, which removes the 'join' column.

Change this line:

```
INNER Join "analytics_poc"."stg_orderitemtag" as t2 ON t1.orderitemid=t2.orderitemid
```

into:

```
INNER Join "analytics_poc"."stg_orderitemtag" as t2 ON USING(orderitemid)
```